# Can we construct differential geometry without multi-variable calculus?

Tags: differential-geometry, multilinear-algebra

To define the basic constructions of differential geometry (for example, the partial derivative of a function over a manifold), the general tactic seems to be to convert discussions of objects over the manifold into discussions of objects living in $\mathbb{R}^i$ by using the charts.

An example off the top of my head is something like so:

1. Define things over the manifold directly, such as functions $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
2. use the charts $(U\subset M, \phi: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n)$ to locally convert parts of the manifold into $\mathbb{R}^n$
3. now use the chart to construct $f'= f \circ \phi^{-1}$  to convert discussions of $f$ over the manifold into discussions over $f': \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Now we have a "calculus-able" object $f'$ in our hands, so we proceed to use calculus to define things like partial derivatives of $f'$, and their relationship to $f$.

However, to perform this (and other) constructions, we need to have the integral and differential structure of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Is there some way to "escape" this, and build these structures into the manifold?

Comment: To clarify, do you mean that you are looking for a $global$ definition of, say, a partial derivative of a  function over a manifold?

Comment: Indeed, or if that is lacking, some definition of a partial derivative that does not wind up using the differential structure of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to define the differential structure on the manifold $M$.

I feel like the reliance on $\mathbb{R}^n$  is weird :)

Comment: I'll defer to the answer below, see Ivo Terek's comment.

Comment: Why do you think the reliance on $\Bbb{R}^n$ is weird? Do you think it is weird that we use flat maps to help us navigate around the world? The essence of a manifold is that it is a space that looks locally like $\Bbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Isn't $\mathbb{R}^n$ quite arbitrary? Why not $\mathbb{C}^n$? Other weirder spaces? why a field, why not a ring? etc. I understand that we pick $\mathbb{R}^n$ since we wish to redefine calculus, but it feels somewhat ad-hoc, I suppose.

Comment: Mathematicians do glue together other structures. For a far reaching generalization (of sorts) look at _schemes_ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_(mathematics)

Comment: I am not posting an answer, because I only have very shallow knowledge of this area, but there is *synthetic differential geometry* in which algebraic geometric approaches are used to do differential geometry. It still relies on local structures, but those are defined in terms of infinitesimal neightborhoods, and calculus is strictly algebraic in nature.

It is also possible to define manifolds in a sheaf theoretic manner without the rest of the synthetic machinery, but it is not essentially different from the usual definition. You still want the structure sheaf to be...

Comment: ... locally isomorphic to the structure sheaf of $\mathbb R^n$, so it is not *really* different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if the following helps you.

Generally, a manifold is a set $M$ to gether with a collection of subsets $\{U_i\}$ and maps $$\phi_i:U_i\to K^n,$$ where $K$ is a field. Any ultra properties on $\phi_i$s makes different names and applications of the manifold. For example, the ordinary manifolds theory is the case $K=\mathbb{R}$, which can inherit properties of $\mathbb{R}$, like differentiability or even "the order" of $\mathbb{R}$.

For complex manifolds, i.e. the case $K=\mathbb{C}$, we deal with analytic functions $\phi_i$ and other concepts like Riemann surfaces or "Klein surfaces" and so on.

There is also quaternionic manifolds, $K=\mathbb{H}$, requiring $\phi_i$ to be "regular" (satisfying Riemann-Fejer equations) or again power series.

You can even go further and speak of "$p$-adic manifolds" (the case $K=\mathbb{Q}_p$).

What I am trying to say, is that being differentiable is not a special property of a manifold. In fact differentiable manifolds are a special cases in the world of  general manifolds.

Comment: Thank you, this along with @Ethan's answers are close to the spirit of my admittedly vague question :)

Comment: Quick question: what happens if we pick $K^n$ to be rings?

Comment: @SiddharthBhat Well it depends on you, in fact your purpose. For example, once I considered $\mathbb{Z}/(n)$ the integers modulo $n$ in a work about Steenrod algebra.

Answer (score 4):

Manifolds are *defined* via charts.

Comment: I agree. perhaps my question is not clear: We use charts to endow a local $\mathbb{R}^n$ structure on every neighbourhood. However, we use this to "descend to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is there some way to perform "calculus in the abstract" without having to rely on our knowledge of calculus over $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Peter's point probably is that you can't even define a manifold without calculus in $\Bbb R^n$. A differentiable atlas is an atlas having all possible changes of coordinates being differentiable maps between open sets of Euclidean spaces.

Comment: Hm, I see. I was hoping for a case where the differential structure could "arise from algebra" without any need for referring to "previously known analysis (structure of $\mathbb{R}^n$).